# three.js getting the front face of a cube

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, cubes

I am currently playing around with this example here:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html

and I am wondering if it is possible to know which side of the cube is currently the front side, means: The side pointing to the camera. Until now I have no clue how to find that out.

Any help is appreciated.
Michael

Comment: get the vector from the centre of the cube to the camera, and then work out which face on the cube that vector intersects.

Comment: It would be nice if you could be a little more specific.

Comment: He cant really be more specific unless it is the code you are looking for. I was going to suggest the same thing.

Comment: As I am still new to three.js I have practically no idea how to get the vector from the centre of the cube to the camera, for example. I also have no idea how to detect an intersection between a face and a vector. That is what I meant with "more specific".
But at least I have a hint. So thanks anyway.

Comment: I set up a fiddle to show the current state of my struggle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mikel/an86j/4/

It would nice if someone could take a look at why I still do not get any intersections.


Thanks a lot

Michael

Comment: I cleaned my fiddle up: http://jsfiddle.net/mikel/an86j/17/

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example code that might help you out, that looks for the intersection between the mouse and the scene:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Mouse-Tooltip.html

Your version of the code will be much simpler than this; for example, to get the Raycaster starting from the camera and in the direction of the cube's center, try:

```
var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, cube.position.clone().sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
```

Then to get the objects that intersect, for example:

```
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

I hope this helps you get started!